# How to convert the code-examples-java to war file to run under TOMCAT container

Tags: tomcat, docusignapi

I downloaded the code example from DOCUSIGN developer website. It runs great from Eclipse environment. In the production environment, we have a TOMCAT 9.0 and try to deploy the code example java as war file to test the integration.

I updated the example code based on https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/
. After I deployed the war file to tomcat, it appears that TOMCAT server recoganized the war file and redirect to default page eg001. Then the response came back with resources does not exist. I really appreciate any help that guide me to the correct path.

If it is possible to maintain the default easy development using sprint-boot and able to deploy WAR file and TOMCAT server, it will be the best.

Comment: Do you have any errors in tomcat logs?

Comment: Exactly how did you deploy the WAR file to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

I you are using Eclipse, you can use [this process](https://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/eclipse-create-deployable-war-file-for-java-web-application):

Click **File > Export**… from main menu (shortcut: Alt + F + O).

Then under **Web**, choose **WAR file** and proceed.